# Call a method in the super from a child popupviewcontroller

Tags: ios, ipad

I need to call a method in the viewcontroller that creates a popupviewcontroller, from the created popupviewcontroller.

For iPad I create it like this:

```
if (!self.flipsidePopoverController) {
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    controller.delegate = self;
    self.flipsidePopoverController = [[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller] autorelease];
}
if ([self.flipsidePopoverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [self.flipsidePopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
}
else
{
    /// The important part ///
    [self.flipsidePopoverController presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width-320), 0, (self.view.frame.size.width), 10) inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

Now I wish to call a method in my main view controller from within the popup. How can I achieve that?

---

My iPhone equivalent is this:

```
// Creating it //
FlipsideViewController *controller = [[[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
controller.delegate = self;
controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Calling a method from within the popup:

```
if ([self.presentingViewController isKindOfClass:[MainViewController class]])
    [(MainViewController*)self.presentingViewController resetClock];
```

Comment: I tried to edit JustSid's answer. Don't import in FlipsideViewController.h, do it in FlipsideViewController.m.  Do you have "@class MainViewController;" above "at"interface FlipsideViewController.... in JustSid's example? (I was only allowed one at symbol, sorry for the "at")

Comment: Ah, cool. Will try that quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the displayed view controller a reference to your main view controller. Eg:

```
@class MainViewController;
@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController
{
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) MainViewController *mainController;

@end
```

(Don't forget the `@synthesize` in the implementation!)
Later when you present the popover, just set the property:

```
[controller setMainController:self];
```

Comment: This gives an `Unknown type name 'MainViewController'; did you mean 'UIViewController'?` error at the `@property ...` line. I have imported MainViewController.h

Comment: Ah, I got this working, but what worked better was: `[(MainViewController *)self.delegate resetClock]`

Answer (score 0):

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit>
#import AppDelegate.h"

@interface FlipsideViewController : UIViewController
{
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) MainViewController *mainController;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "FlipsideViewController.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"

@interface FlipsideViewController ()

@end

@implementation FlipsideViewController

@synthesize mainController = _mainController;

// methods

@end
```